# C++ what to return for the vector::back() on an empty vector

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose that I have a class with a vector data member, and a function to get last element of the vector and returns integer. How can I handle the case in this function that vector is empty? what should I return?

```
class Test
{
private:
   std::vector<stack<int>> vec_;
public:
    void push(int v);
    int GetElement();
};

stack<int> Test::GetElement()
{
    if(!vec_.empty())
        return vec_.back();
    else
       // I want to return something that shows me my vector is empty, 
       // So later on I can use this function to instantiate a stack and push to the vector, 
       // if there is none. what should I do in here????
}
```

Edit: I changed the GetElement() to return a stack*. This way I can return nullptr in case of vector being empty.

Comment: You are the only one who knows the answer to the question of "what should your program return in this situation".

Comment: The title of this post isn't a question and is difficult to understand. The question itself sounds a bit like homework and is not one that can be answer without knowing more about your specific requirements.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Changed the questions to be more clear

Comment: You aren't even calling `std::vector::pop()`.

Comment: Generally speaking, you would not rely on a `GetElement` function to also tell you whether or not there's an element. E.g. consider `std::vector`, it just causes UB if you `back()` when empty but it is still very usable.

Answer (score 4):

Throw an exception, fire an assertion, or return an empty optional, depending on the relevant preconditions.

Comment: A sentinel value is another option

Comment: @Puppy Problem with this solution is that, I do not want to put the code in try catch, just want to have an if else, which if I got an element, I continue, otherwise instantiate a stack and push it into vector